# How can i make Firebase SDK work with MapBox Package in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I tried putting both packages (for firebase i had Auth, Database, Storage) even on an empty project but i still got errors regarding the gradle. I tried changing the AndroidManifest and GradleTemplate but i got into other errors. I tried changing version of BaseGradle as some sources suggested but it didn't work. I tried using Force Resolve after each package import, i tried deleting Library/bee/android folder and deleting Resolved Libraries and also enabling Use R8 but nothing. The errors i am getting on empty project are: [image]

and the error text is in this order:

```
> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
aapt2.exe W 08-17 21:24:50 27252 44092 LoadedArsc.cpp:657] Unknown chunk type '200'.

> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
31 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 22 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

----------NEXT ONE----------

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  
  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

----------NEXT ONE----------

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and support-compat-25.1.0-runtime.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  
  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
aapt2.exe W 08-17 21:24:50 27252 44092 LoadedArsc.cpp:657] Unknown chunk type '200'.

> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
31 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 22 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

----------NEXT ONE----------

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 35 seconds (35380 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

----------NEXT ONE----------

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I really have no idea what i can to to remedy this. If anyone can help i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You have duplicate libraries. You need to use the android resolver to figure out a set of libraries that satisfies the dependencies. Make sure you set the option to use AndroidX of Jetifier before resolving.

Comment: What versions of Unity, EDM4U and Firebase SDK's are you using?

Have you run through the debug steps listed in ["Debugging the Game Build, Install and Run Process"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/build-debug-guide)?